# Tradução de “full volume”

Tags: expressões, tradução-inglês, tradução, vocabulário

Em inglês tem uma expressão “music at full volume” e eu quero saber como traduzi-la em português.

Comment: Dependendo o contexto, se fosse traduzir isso de forma informal com gírias, talvez seria: "música com o volume no talo" (https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_talo)

Answer (score 4):

O mais comum seria **"volume máximo"**.

"Estava ele a ouvir música no volume máximo."

Exemplos da web:s

> - "música eletrônica para ouvir no [volume máximo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b8D4jh9tmA)
> - Eu sempre colocava músicas para tocar e, frequentemente, ouvia Frank Sinatra no [volume máximo](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Zv4TEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&dq=%22no+volume+m%C3%A1ximo%22&hl=pt-BR&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlpfShwqbxAhUgpZUCHYC-D_YQ6AEwA3oECAgQAg) do aparelho.

Menos frequentemente, ouço "a todo o volume".

- Ele ligou o rádio a todo o volume"

Answer (score 1):

Se a tradução em questão fosse para o português de Portugal então esta seria "**música com o volume no máximo**" em vez de "música no volume máximo" como @Centaurus respondeu, sendo esta última tradução mais comum no Brasil. Por exemplo:

> "Ouço Pink Floyd com o volume no máximo."